# How does a (mysql) process know "its" terminal if not from stdio?

Tags: terminal, process, io-redirection, mysql

One thing with the `mysql` program caught my attention. It can be told to ask for password interactively with the `-p` flag, in which case, as you would expect, a prompt appears in your terminal and whatever is put in is accepted as the password. What surprised me though is that this happens even if you redirect all three of `std{in,out,err}`:

```
$ mysql -p </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
Enter password:
```

It reads the password properly too. If you redirect `stderr` to a file, you can check if the login failed.

How does the process know which terminal to ask for the password on? Does it check for attached terminals to parent processes?

Comment: you can put a password in a `~/.my.cnf` file if using from a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unix process can read from /dev/tty, and so circumvent redirection.

Comment: Thanks. Really simple. I forgot Unix processes have a notion of controlling terminals.
"One of the attributes of a process is its controlling terminal. Child processes created with `fork` inherit the controlling terminal from their parent process."[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Terminal.html)

Comment: And it may very well write to /dev/tty too, to disable the echo when the user enters the password.

Answer (score 2):

It can call the `isatty` unistd function.

```
NAME
       isatty - test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       int isatty(int fd);

DESCRIPTION
       The  isatty()  function  tests  whether  fd  is an open file descriptor
       referring to a terminal.
```

Probably, as @Gerard H. Pille noted, mysql doesn't check at all but simply uses `/dev/tty` when you call it with `-p`.

#### Some additional detail

I checked into glibc sources the [isatty implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/isatty.c;h=a06e7ecad55eb8b7906c2f3c7872d468afc3e152;hb=glibc-2.9).

It simply uses the `tcgetattr` function to get the terminal capabilities of the file descriptor. If the function returns true, then it is a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

It [uses](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/4f1d7cf5fcb11a3f84cff27e37100d7295e7d5ca/sql-common/get_password.cc#L156) `getpass()` from libc (where available) which is described in man pages as follows:

> The  getpass() function opens /dev/tty (the controlling terminal of the process), outputs the string prompt, turns off echoing, reads one line (the "password"), restores the terminal state and closes /dev/tty again.